# The ambiguity w.r.t date field in Dim_time

Tags: time, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, fact

I have come across a fact table `fact_trips` - composed of columns like

```
 driver_id,
 vehicle_id,
 date ( in the int form  - 'YYYYMMDD')
 timestamp (in milliseconds -  bigint )
 miles,
 time_of_trip
```

I have another `dim_time` - composed of columns like

```
  date ( in the int form  - 'YYYYMMDD'),
  timestamp (in milliseconds -  bigint ),
  month,
  year,
  day_of_week
  day
```

Now when I want to see the trips grouped based on year, I have to join the two tables based on `timestamp` (in bigint) and then group by year from `dim_time`.

Why the hell do we keep date in int form then? Because ultimately, I have to join on timestamp. What needs to be changed?

Also, the dim_time does not have a primary key, hence there are multiple entries for the same date. So, when I join the tables, I get more rows in return than expected.

Answer (score 1):

You should have 2 Dim tables:

1. DIM_DATE: PK = YYYYMMDD
2. DIM_TIME: PK = number. Will hold the same number of records as however many milliseconds there are in a day (assuming you are holding time at the millisecond grain rather than second, minute, etc)

Comment: seems like a good solution,  thank you so much